# Hooking WinAPI functions called from DLL

Tags: winapi, dll, hook

I have a DLL file *library.dll* which contains a function *foo*. The function *foo* calls a WinAPI function *goo*. I wrote an application that calls *foo* from *library.dll*. The problem is that I want to override the call to *goo* function by my own function *hoo* I declared in the application (not in the DLL).

How can I hook the call to *goo* function? I'm not looking for a global hook, I just want to override calls made by application I wrote.

Comment: I gotta remember this, next time I write an obfuscator.  Obfooscatoo.

Comment: You can just use VirtualProtect to make the entry point to `goo` writeable and then splat it with a non-conditional `JMP` to `hoo`.

Comment: But how can I find the entry point to goo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is library called Detours provided by Microsoft Research: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/. You can use it to re-route any API call in Windows.

It does exactly what you describe -- instead of calling into Win32 API, your function gets called. Within that function you are free to do what you want, e.g. you can call again to the original Win32 function or you can return failure code right away or anything you like.

Express edition of Detours is free, but it is limited for non-commercial use on x86 architecture.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to find this article with code that works for me without using Detours: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/funapihook.aspx#Trad

Answer (score 2):

Patch the import descriptor for `goo` in `library.dll`'s import address table. IAT patching is a well known hooking technique for intercepting function calls between two PE modules.